# problem with prepare statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I write this query and it has error what is problem?

```
prepare test from
'select * from ?';
```

what is problem?

what is it's correct form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just put a placeholder wherever you like. Parameter placeholders can appear only in those places inside the statement where you would normally expect an expression. In particular, you cannot use parameter placeholders to parameterize identifiers or entire statement structures. That's why your attempt fails.

Many more useful things regarding prepared statements and Dynamic SQL in MYSQL can be found in [Roland Bouman's blog -> MySQL 5: Prepared statement syntax and Dynamic SQL](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html).

If your intended use is something like:

```
prepare test
  from
    'select * from ?' ;
set @myt := 'myTable' ;
execute test
  using @myt ;
```

it will simply not work. But you can bypass it with:

```
set @myt := 'myTable'
set @qtext := concat('select * from ',@myt) ;
prepare test 
  from @qtext ;
execute test ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried having the table name as a variable. I'm not sure that's allowed. Try the following:

```
PREPARE test FROM "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column = ?";
```

This is kind of a stab in the dark, since you're not providing the error message.

Comment: This is a good example of where one can use `?` inside a prepared statement.

Comment: @ypercube Well it's good to know that I was right, but your answer is certainly superior. The only thing that is missing IMHO is a link to a specification of what you can and can't do.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add a blog post that thoroughly explains this problem and a lot of other techniques regarding prepared statements. I'll add it now.